# Oauth - Merging Accounts-Do Twitter and Facebook use same Oauth Id?

Tags: facebook, twitter, oauth, twitter-oauth, facebook-oauth

I am building a small app that uses Facebook and Twitter credentials to login/register to use it.

I was wondering if once the user has completed registration if there are any known strategies to merge the accounts together if the user were to decide to do so.

One idea is to confirm matching oauth id's-

Meaning, if the user were to sign in Facebook one go-around, and later login with Twitter-- providing that the oauth id's are matching- Boom!- accounts now merged.

Is this an acceptable practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is...drum roll please........

No.